# PHP splitting groups into pages more elegantly?

Tags: php

I have groups of items (e.g. with counts [3,2,0,4,1,0,1,1,1,0,5,2,3]) and I want to have a minimum number of counts per page (except for the last page). array_slice is currently using the counts array as input but ultimately it would be using the corresponding data as input. The final version would only use array_slice once - for the currently viewed page. I was wondering if the code could be made more elegant e.g using special php functions, etc.

Output:

Items per page: 1 num pages: 10

3; 2; 0,4; 1; 0,1; 1; 1; 0,5; 2; 3;

Items per page: 2 num pages: 8

3; 2; 0,4; 1,0,1; 1,1; 0,5; 2; 3;

Items per page: 3 num pages: 5

3; 2,0,4; 1,0,1,1; 1,0,5; 2,3;

Items per page: 4 num pages: 5

3,2; 0,4; 1,0,1,1,1; 0,5; 2,3;

Items per page: 5 num pages: 4

3,2; 0,4,1; 0,1,1,1,0,5; 2,3;

Items per page: 6 num pages: 3

3,2,0,4; 1,0,1,1,1,0,5; 2,3;

```
<?php
    $group_counts = [3,2,0,4,1,0,1,1,1,0,5,2,3];
    splitOntoPages($group_counts, 1);
    splitOntoPages($group_counts, 2);
    splitOntoPages($group_counts, 3);
    splitOntoPages($group_counts, 4);
    splitOntoPages($group_counts, 5);
    splitOntoPages($group_counts, 6);

function splitOntoPages($item_group_counts, $items_per_page) {
    $page_cumul_totals = [0 => 0];
    $page_first_index = [0 => 0];
    $page = 0;

    foreach ($item_group_counts as $group_index => $group_total) {
        $page_cumul_totals[$page] += $group_total;
        if ($page_cumul_totals[$page] >= $items_per_page) {
            $page++;
            $page_first_index[$page] = $group_index + 1;
            $page_cumul_totals[$page] = 0;
        }
    }
    $page_first_index[$page + 1] = $group_index + 1;

    $numPages = count($page_cumul_totals);
    if ($page_cumul_totals[$numPages - 1] == 0) {
        $numPages--;
    }
    echo 'Items per page: '.$items_per_page.' num pages: '.$numPages.'<br>';
    for ($p = 0; $p < $numPages; $p++) {
        $fromIndex = $page_first_index[$p];
        $countOnPage = $page_first_index[$p + 1] - $fromIndex;
        $page_items = array_slice($item_group_counts, $fromIndex, $countOnPage);
        echo implode(',', $page_items).'; ';
    }
    echo '<br><br>';
}
```

My goal is to determine the correct parameters for array_slice based on a given page number... and also to determine the number of pages.

$page_items = array_slice($item_groups, $fromIndex, $countOnPage);

Comment: Your code is working well and you are only seeking for things that could be made better or do you actually have trouble with anything in your code?

Comment: Looks fine to me apart from echos. I'd use a single loop within `splitOntoPages` to return 2D matrix of pages and print them in an another loop outside the function to separate pagination logic from representation.

Comment: Xatenev: Well lately I've been using things like array_map, array_walk, etc, which I think made the code more elegant so I was wondering if there were other things I could use here...

Comment: Danny: the output is correct I think... all use the correct order (3,2,0,4,1,0,1,1,1,0,5,2,3) and they continue on the same page until the count on the page gets too big.

Comment: Danny: I've updated the question... the goal is concerning array_slice, not printing out counts to the page... the printing out the counts is just to verify that the array_slice it working...

Comment: Danny: the counts on the page is the sum of the counts, not the number of the counts. In my code each group is a trainer's group of students. The trainer's students can't be split onto different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually thought up what I was looking for: it is more concise and clearer though perhaps a little less efficient...

```
function splitOntoPages($item_group_counts, $min_count_per_page) {
    $total_groups = count($item_group_counts);
    $page = 0;    
    $i = 0;
    $page_details = [];
    while ($i < $total_groups) {
        for ($n = 1; $n < ($total_groups - $i); $n++) {
            $page_total = array_sum(array_slice($item_group_counts, $i, $n));
            if ($page_total >= $min_count_per_page) {
                $page_details[$page] = ['offset' => $i, 'length' => $n];
                $page++;
                $i += $n;
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        $page_details[$page] = ['offset' => $i, 'length' => $n];
        break;
    }    
    echo "Items per page: $min_count_per_page num pages: ".($page+1)."<br>";
    foreach ($page_details as $page => $details) {
       echo implode(',', array_slice($item_group_counts, $details['offset'], $details['length'])).'; ';
    }    
    echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Getting the items on page x:

```
array_slice($item_group_info, $page_details[$page_index]['offset'], $page_details[$page_index]['length']));
```